# SharpSvn revert

Tags: c#, svn, revert, sharpsvn

I am trying to revert a file/directory to a specific version with the help of SharpSvn. My current approach is working almost perfectly. The problem is that when I ask SVN to give me some information about the recently reverted file, it always claims that it is the latest revision.

### TortoiseSVN:

- Select "Update to revision..."
- Select any revision and to it
- If you take a look into the log, you will see that the revision you've selected in the previous step is highlighted (bold)

### SharpSvn:

- Revert all changes on the working copy
- Do a reverse merge
- Resolve any unresolved merge issues
- That's the related code:

  ```
  public override bool Revert(ICollection<string> fileNamesWithPath, long revision = -1)
  {
      Console.Write("Reverting changes on file {0}... ", GetListOfFilesAsString(fileNamesWithPath));
      SvnRevertArgs revertArgs = new SvnRevertArgs()
      {
          Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity
      };
      bool result = svnClient.Revert(fileNamesWithPath, revertArgs);
      Console.WriteLine(result ? "done" : "failed");

      if (result && revision > -1)
      {
          foreach (string fileNameWithPath in fileNamesWithPath)
          {
              Console.Write("Reverting changes on file {0} to revision {1}... ", fileNameWithPath, revision);
              SvnMergeArgs mergeArgs = new SvnMergeArgs()
              {
                  Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity
              };
              SvnRevisionRange revisionRange = new SvnRevisionRange(SvnRevision.Head, revision);
              result = result && svnClient.Merge(fileNameWithPath, SvnTarget.FromString(fileNameWithPath), revisionRange, mergeArgs);
              Console.WriteLine(result ? "done" : "failed");

              Console.Write("Resolve any eventually unresolved merge issues by taking 'theirs' on file {0}... ", fileNameWithPath);
              SvnResolveArgs resolveArgs = new SvnResolveArgs()
              {
                  Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity
              };
              result = result && svnClient.Resolve(fileNameWithPath, SvnAccept.TheirsFull, resolveArgs);
              Console.WriteLine(result ? "done" : "failed");
          }
      }
      Console.WriteLine();

      return result;
  }
  ```
- No matter if I use `GetStatus()` or `GetInfo()` afterwards, both return the latest revision number.

What is wrong with this approach?

I've also tried to use `svnClient.Update()` and specify the revision. But if I try to commit this file, it tells me "`File 'D:\test.svn\1.txt' is out of date`". So I guess, that's not the way to go.

Best regards,
   Carsten

Comment: The Update to revision step you explain in your last comment is exactly what TortoiseSVN does in 'update to revision'. In that case you haven't reverted to an old revision, but are just looking at that revision. The reverse merge you describe is what you have to do to revert the steps. (You might need to add a final commit if you want to revert it for everyone). The only other option I can think of is creating a branch of the old revision and commit your changes there.